# Keep hover state when navigation tab is expanded

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, menu, hover

Right now I have an accordion style menu built out for left side secondary navigation.

here's a snippet of the HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class='navigation'><a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('1')" >Computer</a>
<div id='1' style='display:none;'>
<ul class='sub'>
<li class='sub-menu'><a href='#'>Free Diagnostic</a></li>
<li class='sub-menu'><a href='#'>Computer Tune Up</a></li>
<li class='sub-menu'><a href='#'>Virus and Spyware Removal</a></li>
<li class='sub-menu'><a href='#'>E-mail Support</a></li>
<li class='sub-menu'><a href='#'>Green PC</a></li>
<li class='sub-menu'><a href='#'>Software Install</a></li>
<li class='sub-menu'><a href='#'>Simple Repair</a></li>
<li class='sub-menu'><a href='#'>Advanced Repair</a></li>
<li class='sub-menu'><a href='computer.php' style='font-weight:bold;' >See All...</a>                     </li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
```

Here is all the js:

```
var animatedcollapse={
divholders: {}, //structure: {div.id, div.attrs, div.$divref, div.$togglerimage}
divgroups: {}, //structure: {groupname.count, groupname.lastactivedivid}
lastactiveingroup: {}, //structure: {lastactivediv.id}
preloadimages: [],

show:function(divids){ //public method
    if (typeof divids=="object"){
    for (var i=0; i<divids.length; i++)
        this.showhide(divids[i], "show")
}
else
        this.showhide(divids, "show")
},

hide:function(divids){ //public method
    if (typeof divids=="object"){
        for (var i=0; i<divids.length; i++)
            this.showhide(divids[i], "hide")
    }
    else
        this.showhide(divids, "hide")
},

toggle:function(divid){ //public method
    if (typeof divid=="object")
        divid=divid[0]
    this.showhide(divid, "toggle")
},

addDiv:function(divid, attrstring){ //public function
    this.divholders[divid]=({id: divid, $divref: null, attrs: attrstring})
    this.divholders[divid].getAttr=function(name){ //assign getAttr() function to each     divholder object
        var attr=new RegExp(name+"=([^,]+)", "i") //get name/value config pair (ie: width=400px,)
        return (attr.test(this.attrs) && parseInt(RegExp.$1)!=0)? RegExp.$1 : null     //return value portion (string), or 0 (false) if none found
    }
    this.currentid=divid //keep track of current div object being manipulated (in the event of chaining)
return this
},

showhide:function(divid, action){
    var $divref=this.divholders[divid].$divref //reference collapsible DIV
    if (this.divholders[divid] && $divref.length==1){ //if DIV exists
        var targetgroup=this.divgroups[$divref.attr('groupname')] //find out which     group DIV belongs to (if any)
    if ($divref.attr('groupname') && targetgroup.count>1 && (action=="show" ||     action=="toggle" && $divref.css('display')=='none')){ //If current DIV belongs to a group
        if (targetgroup.lastactivedivid &&     targetgroup.lastactivedivid!=divid) //if last active DIV is set
            this.slideengine(targetgroup.lastactivedivid, 'hide')     //hide last active DIV within group first
                this.slideengine(divid, 'show')
            targetgroup.lastactivedivid=divid //remember last active DIV
        }
        else{
            this.slideengine(divid, action)
        }
    }
},

slideengine:function(divid, action){
    var $divref=this.divholders[divid].$divref
    var $togglerimage=this.divholders[divid].$togglerimage
    if (this.divholders[divid] && $divref.length==1){ //if this DIV exists
        var animateSetting={height: action}
        if ($divref.attr('fade'))
            animateSetting.opacity=action
        $divref.animate(animateSetting, $divref.attr('speed')?     parseInt($divref.attr('speed')) : 500, function(){
            if ($togglerimage){
                $togglerimage.attr('src', ($divref.css('display')=="none")?     $togglerimage.data('srcs').closed : $togglerimage.data('srcs').open)
            }
            if (animatedcollapse.ontoggle){
                try{
                    animatedcollapse.ontoggle(jQuery, $divref.get(0),     $divref.css('display'))
                }
                catch(e){
                    alert("An error exists inside your \"ontoggle\"     function:\n\n"+e+"\n\nAborting execution of function.")
                }
            }
        })
        return false
    }
},

generatemap:function(){
    var map={}
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        if (arguments[i][1]!=null){ //do not generate name/value pair if value is null
            map[arguments[i][0]]=arguments[i][1]
        }
    }
    return map
},

init:function(){
    var ac=this
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    animatedcollapse.ontoggle=animatedcollapse.ontoggle || null
        var urlparamopenids=animatedcollapse.urlparamselect() //Get div ids that should be expanded based on the url (['div1','div2',etc])
        var persistopenids=ac.getCookie('acopendivids') //Get list of div ids that should be expanded due to persistence ('div1,div2,etc')
        var groupswithpersist=ac.getCookie('acgroupswithpersist') //Get list of group names that have 1 or more divs with "persist" attribute defined
        if (persistopenids!=null) //if cookie isn't null (is null if first time page loads, and cookie hasnt been set yet)
            persistopenids=(persistopenids=='nada')? [] : persistopenids.split(',') //if no divs are persisted, set to empty array, else, array of div ids
        groupswithpersist=(groupswithpersist==null || groupswithpersist=='nada')? [] : groupswithpersist.split(',') //Get list of groups with divs that are persisted
        jQuery.each(ac.divholders, function(){ //loop through each collapsible DIV object
            this.$divref=$('#'+this.id)
            if ((this.getAttr('persist') || jQuery.inArray(this.getAttr('group'), groupswithpersist)!=-1) && persistopenids!=null){ //if this div carries a user "persist" setting, or belong to a group with at least one div that does
            var cssdisplay=(jQuery.inArray(this.id, persistopenids)!=-1)? 'block' : 'none'
        }
        else{
            var cssdisplay=this.getAttr('hide')? 'none' : null
        }
        if (urlparamopenids[0]=="all" || jQuery.inArray(this.id, urlparamopenids)!=-1){ //if url parameter string contains the single array element "all", or this div's ID
            cssdisplay='block' //set div to "block", overriding any other setting
        }
        else if (urlparamopenids[0]=="none"){
            cssdisplay='none' //set div to "none", overriding any other setting
        }
        this.$divref.css(ac.generatemap(['height', this.getAttr('height')], ['display', cssdisplay]))
        this.$divref.attr(ac.generatemap(['groupname', this.getAttr('group')], ['fade', this.getAttr('fade')], ['speed', this.getAttr('speed')]))
        if (this.getAttr('group')){ //if this DIV has the "group" attr defined
            var targetgroup=ac.divgroups[this.getAttr('group')] || (ac.divgroups[this.getAttr('group')]={}) //Get settings for this group, or if it no settings exist yet, create blank object to store them in
            targetgroup.count=(targetgroup.count||0)+1 //count # of DIVs within this group
            if (jQuery.inArray(this.id, urlparamopenids)!=-1){ //if url parameter string contains this div's ID
                targetgroup.lastactivedivid=this.id //remember this DIV as the last "active" DIV (this DIV will be expanded). Overrides other settings
                targetgroup.overridepersist=1 //Indicate to override persisted div that would have been expanded
            }
            if (!targetgroup.lastactivedivid && this.$divref.css('display')!='none' || cssdisplay=="block" && typeof targetgroup.overridepersist=="undefined") //if this DIV was open by default or should be open due to persistence                               
                targetgroup.lastactivedivid=this.id //remember this DIV as the last "active" DIV (this DIV will be expanded)
            this.$divref.css({display:'none'}) //hide any DIV that's part of said group for now
        }
    }) //end divholders.each
    jQuery.each(ac.divgroups, function(){ //loop through each group
        if (this.lastactivedivid && urlparamopenids[0]!="none") //show last "active" DIV within each group (one that should be expanded), unless url param="none"
            ac.divholders[this.lastactivedivid].$divref.show()
    })
    if (animatedcollapse.ontoggle){
        jQuery.each(ac.divholders, function(){ //loop through each collapsible DIV object and fire ontoggle event
            animatedcollapse.ontoggle(jQuery, this.$divref.get(0), this.$divref.css('display'))
        })
    }
    //Parse page for links containing rel attribute
    var $allcontrols=$('a[rel]').filter('[rel^="collapse["], [rel^="expand["], [rel^="toggle["]') //get all elements on page with rel="collapse[]", "expand[]" and "toggle[]"
    $allcontrols.each(function(){ //loop though each control link
        this._divids=this.getAttribute('rel').replace(/(^\w+)|(\s+)/g, "").replace(/[\[\]']/g, "") //cache value 'div1,div2,etc' within identifier[div1,div2,etc]
        if (this.getElementsByTagName('img').length==1 && ac.divholders[this._divids]){ //if control is an image link that toggles a single DIV (must be one to one to update status image)
            animatedcollapse.preloadimage(this.getAttribute('data-openimage'), this.getAttribute('data-closedimage')) //preload control images (if defined)
            $togglerimage=$(this).find('img').eq(0).data('srcs', {open:this.getAttribute('data-openimage'), closed:this.getAttribute('data-closedimage')}) //remember open and closed images' paths
            ac.divholders[this._divids].$togglerimage=$(this).find('img').eq(0) //save reference to toggler image (to be updated inside slideengine()
            ac.divholders[this._divids].$togglerimage.attr('src', (ac.divholders[this._divids].$divref.css('display')=="none")? $togglerimage.data('srcs').closed : $togglerimage.data('srcs').open)
        }
        $(this).click(function(){ //assign click behavior to each control link
            var relattr=this.getAttribute('rel')
            var divids=(this._divids=="")? [] : this._divids.split(',') //convert 'div1,div2,etc' to array 
            if (divids.length>0){
                animatedcollapse[/expand/i.test(relattr)? 'show' : /collapse/i.test(relattr)? 'hide' : 'toggle'](divids) //call corresponding public function
                return false
            }
        }) //end control.click
    })// end control.each

    $(window).bind('unload', function(){
        ac.uninit()
    })
}) //end doc.ready()
},

uninit:function(){
    var opendivids='', groupswithpersist=''
    jQuery.each(this.divholders, function(){
        if (this.$divref.css('display')!='none'){
            opendivids+=this.id+',' //store ids of DIVs that are expanded when     page unloads: 'div1,div2,etc'
        }
        if (this.getAttr('group') && this.getAttr('persist'))
            groupswithpersist+=this.getAttr('group')+',' //store groups with     which at least one DIV has persistance enabled: 'group1,group2,etc'
    })
    opendivids=(opendivids=='')? 'nada' : opendivids.replace(/,$/, '')
    groupswithpersist=(groupswithpersist=='')? 'nada' : groupswithpersist.replace(/,$/,     '')
    this.setCookie('acopendivids', opendivids)
    this.setCookie('acgroupswithpersist', groupswithpersist)
    },

getCookie:function(Name){ 
    var re=new RegExp(Name+"=[^;]*", "i"); //construct RE to search for target     name/value pair
    if (document.cookie.match(re)) //if cookie found
        return document.cookie.match(re)[0].split("=")[1] //return its value
    return null
},

setCookie:function(name, value, days){
    if (typeof days!="undefined"){ //if set persistent cookie
    var expireDate = new Date()
    expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()+days)
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+"; path=/;     expires="+expireDate.toGMTString()
    }
else //else if this is a session only cookie
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+"; path=/"
},

urlparamselect:function(){
window.location.search.match(/expanddiv=([\w\-_,]+)/i) //search for expanddiv=divid     or divid1,divid2,etc
return (RegExp.$1!="")? RegExp.$1.split(",") : []
},

preloadimage:function(){
var preloadimages=this.preloadimages
for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    if (arguments[i] && arguments[i].length>0){
        preloadimages[preloadimages.length]=new Image()
        preloadimages[preloadimages.length-1].src=arguments[i]
    }
}
}

}
```

here is my CSS:

```
}#navigation{
width: 290px;
height: 347px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation ul{
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
padding-left:4px;
margin-top: -1px;
}

#navigation ul li{
position: relative;
width: 282px;
}

.navigation a:link, .navigation a:active, .navigation a:visited{
display: block;
height: 6px;
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
background-image: url('images/buttonfade.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px outset #efefef;
}

.navigation a:hover{
color: #000;
background-image: url('images/buttonfade.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px inset #efefef;
}

.sub{
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
}

.sub-menu a:link, .sub-menu a:active, .sub-menu a:visited{
display: block;
width: 260px;
height: 100%;
padding: 10px;
color: #000;
background-image: none;
background-color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
font-size: .78em;
margin: 0;
border: none;
font-weight: normal;
border: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.sub-menu a:hover{
color: #000;
background-color: #efefef;
background-image: none;
text-decoration: underline;
border: 1px solid #efefef;
}
.sub-menu a:hover{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #efefef;
    background-image: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
}
```

I would like to figure out a way to make the hover state stay active if the tab is opened to reveal the sub menu. That way it makes which category they have open stand out more. This is code from a tutorial I used, so I don't understand 95% of the JavaScript.

It would also be very helpful if someone could tell me how to use JavaScript to add a downward facing triangle/arrow to the end of each tab in my navigation that has a sub menu, since not all of the buttons do, and I would like people to know that there is more content under that tab.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".navigation").click(function(){
     alert('I have been clicked');

     $(this).toggleClass('active');

  });

});
```

CSS:

```
.active { 
    color: #000;
    background-image: url('images/buttonfade.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px inset #efefef;
}
```

Comment: where exactly should i be putting the jquery script? because where I just put it does nothing....

Comment: Anywhere, as long as it is either after the HTML, or on $(document).ready();

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work. i have it in the head section and it never even picks it up. i may have to try another route anyhow, because i also need the menus to stay expanded depending on the page as well. thanks for your feedback though!

Comment: I have changed my answer a little, make sure you use `$(document).ready`. Also make sure that whatever you want to click has the class name 'navigation' and that class name 'active' exists. Use Google Chrome's Inspector or Firefox' FireBug to make sure the function gets called